# ASP.NET MVC 3, user defined id for field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can any one help?

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.property, new { id = "some value" })` is not working. When i view the source it displays the element id as `"id=model.property"`

How do i resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to prefix the generated id, you could use `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` property. Otherwise, you could use Html.TextBox, Html.CheckBox, etc... or write the entire input element tag yourself.

Comment: Thank you archil, let me try your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.property, new { @id = "some-value" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default behavior by using your version of EditorFor.

Another option is javascript, add a javascript to change the id of the control on page load

Comment: Thank you Jani, let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
<input name="property.id" value="@some-value"/>
```

Or you can try TyroneMichael's tip.